# how to block subdomain from any domain with windows7?

Tags: windows-7, security, firewall, internet-security, subdomain

There are a lot of crappy websites which install spyware or badware software with a  common subdomain name.

For example (don't try these URLs, they are dangerous):

```
4d0a8a26-a90a-43b8-90c6-250af10ac981.alerte-sur.com
4d0a8a26-a90a-43b8-90c6-250af10ac981.alertecomputer.com
```

So, I want to block any webpage with '4d0a8a26-a90a-43b8-90c6-250af10ac981' in the subdomain name ?

How can I configure that under Windows 7?

Remember that I don't know the name of the domain, I want to block `4d0a8a26-a90a-43b8-90c6-250af10ac981.anydomain.any-extention`

Does Windows 7 allow to do that? Maybe with the HOST file?

My internet router is an Orange Livebox, maybe there is a setting to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Windows 7. But it can be done with chrome extensions. 
[Blocksite](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-site/eiimnmioipafcokbfikbljfdeojpcgbh/) is a extension available for Chrome and Firefox that can block any site with a keyword.

```
4d0a8a26-a90a-43b8-90c6-250af10ac981.alerte-sur.com
4d0a8a26-a90a-43b8-90c6-250af10ac981.alertecomputer.com
```

If you put `4d0a8a26-a90a-43b8-90c6-250af10ac981` in blocked words, then it will block all urls containing that word.